# static template and javascript template collide, static wins

Tags: javascript, python

I have an initial template with form inputs suggested by the following code.

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <div id="main" >
        <input type="text" id="r0t0p1" name="r0t0p1" value="name1"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

After the user sees the input I regenerate the "revised" form with javascript as suggested by the following excerpt. The dictionary `dict` in the javascript has been created in Python to pass updated user inputs back to the template when it is regenerated by the javascript.

```
var tT='';
            tT += '<input type="text" id="r'+ r +'t'+ t + 'p1" name="r'+ r +'t'+ t + 'p1">{% raw %}{{ dict.r'+ r +'t'+ t + 'p1 }}{% endraw %}</input>'
```

My problem is that although the `dict` values have been updated correctly and the ndb google datastore contains all of the revised input values, the "revised" javascript generated template is obliterated by the original static template. I can even see the correctly revised template flash on the screen, but it is replaced by the original static one.

What can I do to fix this so that the revised information persists?
There may be more information you need, please ask.

**edit 0 below**

I have placed a dumbed down version [at jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/yzagv6b4/103/) and I have noticed that there is no update of the output when the "Load Type" is either "onLoad" or "onDomready", but if the "Load Type" is either "No wrap-in " or "No wrap-in " then the results update. I am not familiar with "Load Types" but does this information suggest a fix? Click on `Add a cell` or `Add a row` to exercise the app on fiddle. (Btw, I editted the link address because I was not aware that the update level was required in the link address.)

Also, my Python code for (retrieving and) creating the screen looks like the following. Is there something I can change in this code?

```
class Host(BaseHandler):

    def post(self,ID):
    tables=int(self.request.get('tables'))
    rounds=int(self.request.get('rounds'))
    key = ndb.Key(Pages,ID,Parties,ID)

    return webapp2.redirect("/host/%s" % ID)

    def get(self, ID):

    template_values = {'ID':ID, 'dict': dict}
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('host.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render( template_values))
    #self.render_template('host.html', {'ID': ID, 'dict': dict})
```

**edit 0 above**

Answer (score 0):

This is only a **partial** answer (but see far below).

By adding a `onbeforeunload="myFunction()"` event to my `<body>` element I got clear evidence that an unload is occurring when user clicks any button in my app. That unload is triggering my static original template to reload and wiping out the desired "revised" template as described in my question.

My `<form>` element triggers the unload, and so I removed it and the collision is avoided. But...

I still am clueless about how to include the values of my `{{dict.xxxx}}` data from the datastore in the "revised" template. Instead of seeing the value of each `{{dict.xxxx}}`, I literally see `{{dict.xxxx}}`, curly brackets and all. So maybe the `<form>` element also enables the datastore values to be retrieved, but I doubt it. So I'm still in the weeds.

Please suggest ideas (like telling me to ask a new question).

**edit**

Completing the answer:

I no longer used the jinja2 `{{dict.xxxx}}` in the `<script>` code section because I could not make that work. Instead, in the non`<script>` section using javascript and jinja I built a series of "hidden" `<input>`s, each containing an item from the dictionary and a unique id constructed from prepending the string 'dict' to the id of each datum. I used an idea found at [this link "Using data attributes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) . But my approach was used `getattribute()` instead because the article warned that features of data are not universally available in browsers.